# How do I get the user details straight after login using Identity on ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity to do the authentication on my website and I'm trying to log user id to the DB as soon as they login but I don't seem to be able to access them using the following code. The `GetResult()` returns null here but it works fine if it's on the next page, but just not in the `OnPostAsync` method where it needs to be.
`Input.UserIDOrLogonName` does not contain the user id.

```
private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserIDOrLogonName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var userId = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)
                         .GetAwaiter().GetResult().UserId;
            _audit.RecordAction(AuditType.LoginSuccess, userId);
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
```

Is there any other way to get to the instance of the User?

Comment: What is it that does not work? What does the view look like?

Comment: I've just updated the question with details of what doesn't work, ie. the GetResult() is null.  Not sure what you mean about the view

Comment: With view I mean the mvc page (html) that posts to the controller

Comment: It's just a basic login form with username and password fields.

Comment: Have you debugged using F12 Developer tools (in Chrome or IE). Are the fields actually posted to your controller?

Comment: @user2145210 I have also faced this problem. I shall inspect this thing tomorrow.

Comment: I’ve had this problem myself. Basically, as soon as it signs in, the identity has not yet been attached to the context. That’s why it’s only in the next call that you get the identity. What I ended up doing is having a custom signinmanager and overrode the passwordsignin to return the identity along with the signinresult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `HttpContext.User`, it will work for sub-request after loging.

If you want to log UserId, try to find the user by email like

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
    var userId = user.Id;
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that's almost what I needed, many thanks.  In the end I found this: _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserIDOrLogonName);